# Setting up 3DCart API with a C# App

Tags: c#, xml

I have been trying to create an application to go through our database at a set interval and update/add any new items to 3DCarts database. Their code example uses soap in an xml file to send 1 request per call. So I need to to be able to generate the xml I need with the items information on the fly before sending it. I have done hardly anything with XML files like this and cannot figure out how to create the chunk of code I need and send it. One method that has been suggested is create a file but still executing has been a problem and would be very inefficient for a large number of items. Here is what I have so far

```
    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '" + Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0)) + "'";
            ServiceReferenceCart.cartAPIAdvancedSoapClient bcsClient = new ServiceReferenceCart.cartAPIAdvancedSoapClient();
            ServiceReferenceCart.runQueryResponse bcsResponse = new ServiceReferenceCart.runQueryResponse();

            bcsClient.runQuery(storeUrl, userKey, sqlStatement, callBackURL);
            string result = Convert.ToString(bcsResponse);

            listBox1.Items.Add(result);
```

EDIT: Changed from sample code block to current code block as I got a service reference setup finally. They provide no details though for using the functions in the reference. With this bcsResponse is just a blank, when I try adding .Body I have the same result but when I add .runQuery to the .Body I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. As I have said I have not messed with service references before.

I hope I have explained well enough I just really have not worked with this kind of stuff before and it has become extremely frustrating.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring this out after playing around with it. Here is what I did to get the reference to work. This may have been easy for anyone who have used the references before but I have not and have decided to post this in case anyone else has this problem. The SQL can be SELECT, ADD, UPDATE and DELETE statements this was to see if the sku was listed before updating/adding.

```
            //Will be using these multiple times so a variable makes more sense
            // DO NOT include http:// in the url, also id is not shown in their
            //database layout pdf they will give but it is the sku/product number
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT id FROM products WHERE id = '" + Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(0)) + "')))";
            string userKey = "YourKeyHere";
            string storeUrl = "YourStoresURLHere";

            // Setting up instances from the 3DCart API
            cartAPIAdvancedSoapClient bcsClient = new cartAPIAdvancedSoapClient();
            runQueryRequest bcsRequest = new runQueryRequest();
            runQueryResponse bcsResponse = new runQueryResponse();
            runQueryResponseBody bcsRespBod = new runQueryResponseBody();
            runQueryRequestBody bcsReqBod = new runQueryRequestBody();

            //assigning required variables to the requests body
            bcsReqBod.storeUrl = storeUrl;
            bcsReqBod.sqlStatement = sqlStatement;
            bcsReqBod.userKey = userKey;

            //assigning the body to the request
            bcsRequest.Body = bcsReqBod;

            //Setting the response body to be the result
            bcsRespBod.runQueryResult = bcsClient.runQuery(bcsReqBod.storeUrl, bcsReqBod.userKey, bcsReqBod.sqlStatement, bcsReqBod.callBackURL );
            bcsResponse.Body = bcsRespBod;

            //adding the result to a string
            string result = bcsResponse.Body.runQueryResult.Value;

            //displaying the string, this for me was more of a test
            listBox1.Items.Add(result);
```

You will also need to activate the Advanced API on your shop as you may notice there is no actual option as the pdf's say, you need to go to their store and purchase(its free) and wait for them to activate it. This took about 2 hrs for us.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. i have looked all over the web for 3dCart API examples to get me started.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it could help someone as the documentation when I was working on it was dreadful.